# Which Django/Pinax app should I use? There are so many, and I just want the simplest one

Tags: python, django, pinax, profiles

- I want a "settings" page where the
  user can submit his
  hometown/biography/email settings and upload his avatar
- We will be building a mobile app that uses HTTP Rest API to update the user's profile, so we must be able to do manual override of these apps.

That's it! I don't want anything else. I don't care about the friending or blogging or anything.

Which Django App should I use? Currently, I am using **Pinax's basic_project**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-profile](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home) may be of use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I actually am approaching the same problem.

I find overriding the pinax profile app is enough. The profile section is what allows the upload of avatars and your info and allows you to also edit it.

I still haven't found a good way to override the native apps yet. Right now I am copying over the app.

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 0):

I generally like starting with the basic or account, then build up to what I need. I prefer this method to starting with complete/social and stripping out what I don't need. Just fyi.